# Problems extending the marshal library

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling

I am writing a project in c++/cli that is translating between C# and the CryptoAPI.  Because of this I am having to do quite a bit of marshaling back and forth and in some cases I have extended the marshaling library to make some of this easier.  In some cases when I compile I get the following message:

> error C4996:
>   'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper
>   ^,_From_Type,false>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by
>   the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not
>   included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the
>   Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\msclr\marshal.h

I know what the error means and in several cases, it's been because I forgot to add a header to a class.  However, when it's not that, this error is VERY hard to track down.  Since the actual error points to inside the marshal.h file, there's no clue (that I can see) as to where the actual problem is.  The only way I've found to get around this is every time I write a line of code that uses marshaling, I have to stop and compile to make sure that particular line is correct.  You can imagine how much that is slowing me down.  Does anyone know of a better way to find where this error is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried this, it did report a line number to me. Can you show an example where it doesn't?

My test code:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int i = 7;
    std::string foo = marshal_as<std::string>(i);
}
```

Build output:

```
------ Build started: Project: QuickieCppCLI, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
  QuickieCppCLI.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\msclr\marshal.h(237): error C4996: 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.
          with
          [
              _To_Type=std::string,
              _From_Type=int
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\msclr\marshal.h(217) : see declaration of 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper::marshal_as'
          with
          [
              _To_Type=std::string,
              _From_Type=int
          ]
          QuickieCppCLI.cpp(114) : see reference to function template instantiation '_To_Type msclr::interop::marshal_as(const _From_Type &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _To_Type=std::string,
              _From_Type=int
          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Note the line 7th from the bottom: `QuickieCppCLI.cpp(114) : see reference to function template instantiation...`. That's the `marshal_as` line in my main method.

Comment: I'm not seeing that much information, but I'm sure that I'm just not seeing it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DrewBurchett: Close the Issue List, Error List, or whatever.  It's useless for template errors.  Use the build output, which looks like what David Yaw pasted.  The problem is that everything that says "with" or "see reference to" isn't actually an error, so it doesn't get shown in the error list.  (besides, trying to put all of that into a single line in a listbox is not going to end well).  Just view the actual compiler output.

Comment: @DrewBurchett To show the output window, Go to Tools::Options, Projects and Solutions, check "Show Output window when build starts", and clear "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors". I always hide the Error List, so I sometimes forget that it doesn't show the full error text.